# Create Fishnet with row iterator (in python) - Number of rows and columns not sufficient?

Tags: arcpy, vector-grid

I have a shapefile that contains over 100 squares of different sizes and I want to divide each of the squares into quarter sections.

I've written a short python script to do a row iteration and for each square, create a fishnet with 2 rows and 2 columns based on some predefined condition. Since the squares have different sizes, I set the numbers of rows and columns to 2 and set the cell height and width to zero. (Find the script below)

However, I get this error when I run the script although it's only the width/height pair that I set to zero.
"ERROR 000124: These two pair parameters cannot be zero at the same time"

Any suggestions how I can work around this?

SCRIPT:

```
#Loop thru rows of input polygons
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(outfc, ['SHAPE@', 'OID@', 'SumNet']) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        ext = row[0].extent
        st = '%f %f' % (ext.XMin, ext.YMin)
        orien = '%f %f' % (ext.XMin, ext.YMax)

        #Create fishnet
        out = os.path.join(gdb, 'fish_{0}'.format(row[1]))
        if row[2] > threshold:
            arcpy.CreateFishnet_management(out, st, orien, '0', '0', '2', '2', labels='NO_LABELS', geometry_type='POLYGON')
        else:
            #arcpy.Copy_management(row, out)
            arcpy.CreateFishnet_management(out, st, orien, '0', '0', '1', '1', labels='NO_LABELS', geometry_type='POLYGON')
```

Comment: Does this error occur regardless of whether or not your condition is met?

Comment: Exactly, it occurs whether or not the condition is met. The createfishnet works only when I set the cell height and width to a non-zero value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're specifying an Origin Coordinate and a Y-Axis Coordinate you need to also specify the coordinates for the opposite corner.

In your case something like this should work:

```
opp = '%f %f' % (ext.XMax, ext.Ymax)
...
arcpy.CreateFishnet_management(out, st, orien, '0', '0', '2', '2', corner_coord = opp, labels='NO_LABELS', geometry_type='POLYGON')
```

Alternatively you can provide a template extent derived from the extent of the input feature:

```
ext = row[0].extent
...
arcpy.CreateFishnet_management(out, st, orien, '0', '0', '2', '2', template = ext, labels='NO_LABELS', geometry_type='POLYGON')
```

It's worth noting that if you use the Create Fishnet tool via the dialog box, when you select a template the Origin Coordinate, Y-Axis Coordinate and Opposite Corner parameters are auto-filled. However, when calling from a python script you will still have to specify these values when using a template.